# rotate numbers on x axis

Tags: pgfplots, rotating, ticks

I tried a lot, but since gouplot is new, and I can't handle it very well, i couldn't rotate the number on the x_axis.

```
     \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
  group size=1 by 4,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
  vertical sep=0pt,   % vertical distance between axes
 },
 axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
 xmin=0,xmax=10,   % set axis
 ymin=0,           % limits
 domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
 width=10cm,       % width
 height=3cm,       % and height for each axis
 scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
 no markers, 
 enlarge y limits=upper,
 xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=5} %sets the precision
]

\nextgroupplot[
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
    axis x line=none] % remove x-axis lines
 \addplot{x};

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{-x + 10}; 

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{x*x}; 

\nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}]
 \addplot+[samples=200] {abs(sin(x*180/pi))}; 

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `xticklabel style={rotate=-90,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=5}` instead of `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=5}`?

Comment: oh my good, thank you!

Comment: @abcdefg, do you want to write an answer or shall we close the question as answered in the comments?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Either way. Probably closing is easier.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: I'm voting close not because it was answered in the comments (this can easily be turned to a propper answer), but because it is a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tikz picture, rotate x tick labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282929/tikz-picture-rotate-x-tick-labels)

Comment: yes it did, i don't know how to close the topic and vote the correct answer like in the matlab forum